# Why does flutter doctor gives android tollchain error

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, android-sdk-tools, flutter-android

when i type flutter doctor i recieve this one

Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
X Unable to locate Android SDK.
Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
(or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
`flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

For any help - thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

1. install [android-studio](https://developer.android.com/studio?gclid=CjwKCAiA6Y2QBhAtEiwAGHybPRMnjFiL7bb5sqBlQ33eeU9J8IJoKXJL0ErId_l1EAk6z7h1_YQEqhoCpf0QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) in order to develop flutter apps.
2. install [cmd-line-tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line) from android-studio -> sdk-manager -> appearence and behaviour -> system settings -> android sdk -> Android SDK command line tools
3. If you installed android-studio in any other location then add a system variable `ANDROID-HOME` with the path where your android sdk is located

Answer (score 0):

you may need to add ANDROID_HOME to your system variables and the value would be your sdk path